# Reproduce the Android's gallery

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

Being currently developing a mini application whose goal is to reproduce the Android gallery, I can't get my application to work properly.

Indeed, having as constraint to use a canvas and not having the right to use any layout at all, I proceeded in different steps that I will now explain to you in order to explain the problem:

1 - My main activity is running with two objects, a "Scan" object and a "GalleryView" object which are two personal classes

2 - The scan object retrieves all the paths of the images in the gallery using a function.

3 - MainActivity recovers this arraylist and passes it to the builder of my galleryview.

4 - The gallery view knows the number of elements to display (equal to the size of the string arraylist returned by scan) and builds the bitmaps of each image in order to display them

And that's where the problem happens. Indeed, having about 480 images on my phone, as soon as I try to display them all, the for where I browse the list of paths of GalleryView.java is a problem because it crashes the application.

If I decide to draw only 480 times the first image, it works.

So I would like to know how to optimize this behavior to avoid crashes and memory overload.

My teacher advises us to use BitmapDrawable instead of Bitmap but I don't see how to implement it.

You will find below all the classes of my application + the diagram that roughly explains the rendering steps

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    //Objet qui va nous permettre de récuperer les images de la gallerie du téléphone
    ScanPictures m_scan;

    //liste des chemins des images de la gallerie
    ArrayList<String>m_paths;

    //objet qui permet d'afficher les images
    GalleryView m_gallery;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //On créer l'object scanner pour récuperer les photos de la gallerie
        m_scan = new ScanPictures(this.getApplicationContext());

        //Boolean nous indiquant si l'application à l'autorisation d'accéder au contenu interne du téléphone
        Boolean isAuthorized = this.isReadStoragePermissionGranted();

        //Si on est authorisé, on scan la gallerie et on récuperer les chemins des photos
        if(isAuthorized){
            System.out.println("SCAN IMAGES ALREADY GRANTED");
            m_paths = m_scan.getImages();
            System.out.println("SCAN IMAGES ALREADY GRANTED DONE");
        }

        m_gallery = new GalleryView(this.getApplicationContext(),m_paths);
        m_gallery.setPicturesNumber(m_paths.size());
        setContentView(m_gallery);

    }

    public  boolean isReadStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) { //le sdk est supérieur a 23, l'autorisation n'est pas donnée automatiquement
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {

                //L'autorisation n'est pas accordée, on la demande à l'utilisateur
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 3);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //les permissions sont automatiquement données en sdk < 23
            return true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //SI l'utilisateur à donner l'autorisation, on scan les photos
            if (requestCode == 3 ) {
                System.out.println("SCAN IMAGES FIRST GRANTED");
                this.m_scan.getImages();
                System.out.println("SCAN IMAGES FIRST GRANTED DONE");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**GalleryView.java**

```
public class GalleryView extends View {

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGestureDetector;
    private float mScale = 1;
    private Bitmap resized =null;
    private int numColumns, numRows, nbPict;
    private int cellSize;
    private ArrayList<String> m_paths;
    private Context m_context;

    public GalleryView(Context context, ArrayList<String> paths) {
        super(context);

        m_context = context;
        m_paths = paths;
        numColumns = 7;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new ZoomGesture());
        mScaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleGesture());
    }

    public void setPicturesNumber(int nbPict) {
        this.nbPict = nbPict;
        calculateDimensions();
    }


    private void calculateDimensions() {
        numRows = nbPict/numColumns;
        cellSize = getWidth() / numColumns;
        invalidate();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        calculateDimensions();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),R.drawable.alterralogo);
        int bitmapIndex = 0;
        ArrayList<Bitmap> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m_paths.get(0));

        for(int i = 0 ; i< nbPict;i++){
            list.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m_paths.get(i))); //NOT OPTIMISED AT ALL, MAKE THE APP CRASH
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
                    resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(list.get(bitmapIndex), cellSize, cellSize, true);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(resized, i* cellSize, j * cellSize, null);
                    bitmapIndex++;
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        mScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    public class ZoomGesture extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        private boolean normal = true;

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class ScaleGesture extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            if(numColumns !=1){
                numColumns--;
                calculateDimensions();
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**ScanPictures.java**

```
public class ScanPictures {

    Context m_application_context;

    public ScanPictures(Context activity_context){
        m_application_context = activity_context;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getImages(){

        ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>(); //liste qui va contenir les chemins vers les images de la gallerie

        String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME };

        String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? ";

        String selectionArgs[] = {"Camera"};

        String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN;
        //Stores all the images from the gallery in Cursor
        Cursor cursor = m_application_context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, selection, selectionArgs, orderBy);

        //Total number of images
        int count = cursor.getCount();

        //Create an array to store path to all the images
        String[] arrPath = new String[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

            //Store the path of the image
            arrPath[i]= cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
            paths.add(arrPath[i]);

        }

        System.out.println(paths);

        return  paths;
    }
}
```

[image: Main steps of the application]